# Changing preference text color after the layout is constructed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I want to **programmatically** change the text color of all ListPreference in my PreferenceActivity, **after** the layout is constructed (so after `onCreate`). Basically I want to be able to toggle all text between black and white.

I've tried having two themes for both colors, but that requires to restart the activity to toggle between themes. I don't want that.

Can someone come up with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer to my question is that there is no way to do what I wanted. I ended up using two themes for both colors, even though changing the theme will apply after restarting the activity.